# killing process java.exe

Tags: c#

I launch some batch file from my C# app via Process class. This file started java app. I cant recognize which process called java.exe  must be kill to stop this application. Is there some more elegant way than kill them all, hope that i end the right one and dont kill some other important java app?  Thanks for any help I really stuck there.

Cheers,
Andrew

Comment: There should be a OS maintained parent-child relationship between the Java.app and the C# app. I assume you are on windows ? And why do you want to kill this Java process ?

Comment: Yes Iam on windows. Java process is launched by user from my C# app. It do some computations for him. If user decide to stop computation I must kill the java app, because it process huge amount of data and is therefore time expensive. Thanks. I found some maintaining of parent-child relationship I will test it.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: I missed the batch file part.  This answer will only be useful if you can launch the process directly from C#...

When you start the process you can store the process Id so you can get the process back later and kill it.

```
Process p = new Process();
//set all the process start Info...
p.Start();

someVariableICanGetToLater = p.Id

//Later when you need to kill the process...
Process pToKill = Process.GetProcessById(someVariableICanGetToLater);
pToKill.Kill();
```

Comment: It seems he does not know that the Java process is being started, so I doubt he knows where the code is, or perhaps the source is not available.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that, since the batch file launches the Java app, knowing the id of the batch file process won't help.

`Process.GetProcessesByName("java")` gives you a list of all the java.exe instances.

Comment: plus he needs to query the parent child relationship between the C# app and the java processes. Could you post that code ? :P

Answer (score 0):

pseudo code . Fill in OS specific calls here:

```
int cs_pid=getProcessByName("CSharpAppName");
int javaPid[]= getProcessByName("JavaAppName");

bool javaToCSharpRelationship[]=new bool[javaPid.size];

int loopCounter=0;

forEach int in javaPid
begin
      if(isChildOf(cs_pid,java_pid))
      begin
         // OS call or Wrapper to determine relationship between c# pid
         // and Java app PID
         javaToCSharpRelationShip[loopCounter]=true;
         //can call kill here if you like
      end
      else 
         javaToCSharpRelationShip[loopCounter]=false;
     loopCounter++;
end
```

At the end of this code you should have an array of PID's which are children of the C# app.

Comment: Hi,that looks really interesting. Can you give me some hint to isChildOf method?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the batch file does lots of things, hard to accomplish using only .NET's `Process` and `ProcessStartInfo` classes, another option would be to start directly java.exe and control the arguments and environment variables via `ProcessStartInfo`'s `Arguments` and `EnvironmentVariables` properties.

Then you could use Jason's approach to store java.exe process' id in order to kill it later.